# How can we customize SCIM query filter in Azure?

Tags: azure, provisioning, scim

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zn3oG.png)

Azure is using **userName** to apply filter. Can anyone suggest if there is any way to customize this filter? I want to use **userName** + **externalId** to be passed in the filter as parameter.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Attributes set as matching properties in the mappings will be used sequentially to try to identify a match. For example, with userPrincipalName -> userName as matching precedence 1 and objectId -> externalId as matching precedence 2, Azure AD Provisioning would do a GET /Users?filter=userName eq "user@domain.com". If that filtered GET returns zero results, then a GET /Users?filter=externalId eq "GuidValue" would be performed. If both came back with zero results, a POST will be used to create a user, otherwise if one result is found from either of those filtered GET calls, the objects will be linked between systems and a PATCH will be used to update any attributes on the SCIM service's user if needed.

There is no way to jointly call two attributes, such as /Users?filter=username eq "user@domain.com" and externalId eq "GuidValue"

Comment: Yes what you are suggesting is working but it is using two different calls, so I removed userName from precedence and only using externalId and this will work for me.. thanks

Comment: To be clear I did not suggest anything - I explained the behavior that you were seeing and why what you were requesting is not possible.